# Bad value in a file pointer

Tags: perl

This short example illustrates a problem I have in Perl. The idea is to process `stdin` as default or use an input file if specified.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

qx{echo "a file" > a};
qx{echo "b file" > b};
qx{echo "c file" > c};

process('a');
process('c');

sub process {
    my $name = shift;
    my $fp = *STDIN;            
    open $fp,  '<', $name if $name;    
    process('b') if $name eq 'a';

    print "Processing file '$name' (fp=$fp)\n";    
    print while(<$fp>);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
$ ./curious.pl
Processing file 'b' (fp=*main::STDIN)
b file
Processing file 'a' (fp=*main::STDIN)
Processing file 'c' (fp=*main::STDIN)
c file
```

And should be:

```
$ ./curious.pl
Processing file 'b' (fp=*main::STDIN)
b file
Processing file 'a' (fp=*main::STDIN)
a file
Processing file 'c' (fp=*main::STDIN)
c file
```

I am probably missing two things:

- Why does `$fp` is equal to `*main::STDIN` and not to the current opened file?
- Why the content `'a'` is not read?

Logically, `$fp` is local to the subroutine. It is first assigned to `*STDIN` then altered by `open` with a file pointer to `a`. Then I process `b`. When I return to the processing of `b` I should still have a pointer to `a` inside `$fp`.

I've read [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) that handler passed to `open` must be an undefined scalar. However it seems to work with `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to be to do with reassigning `STDIN`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

qx{echo "a file" > a};
qx{echo "b file" > b};
qx{echo "c file" > c};

process('a');
process('c');

sub process {
    my $name = shift;
    print "Starting process with $name from ", scalar caller(), " \n";
    my $fp;    #  = *STDIN;
    print "Process before open $name: ", Dumper($fp), "\n";
    open $fp, '<', $name if $name;
    print "Process  after open $name: ", Dumper($fp), "\n";
    process('b') if $name eq 'a';
    print "Processing file '$name' (fp=$fp)\n";
    print "Contents of $name:\n";
    print while (<$fp>);
    print "Done with $name\n\n\n";
}
```

This gives the output:

```
Starting process with a from main 
Process before open a: $VAR1 = undef;

Process  after open a: $VAR1 = \*{'::$fp'};

Starting process with b from main 
Process before open b: $VAR1 = undef;

Process  after open b: $VAR1 = \*{'::$fp'};

Processing file 'b' (fp=GLOB(0x136412c))
Contents of b:
"b file" 
Done with b


Processing file 'a' (fp=GLOB(0x606f54))
Contents of a:
"a file" 
Done with a


Starting process with c from main 
Process before open c: $VAR1 = undef;

Process  after open c: $VAR1 = \*{'::$fp'};

Processing file 'c' (fp=GLOB(0x136412c))
Contents of c:
"c file" 
Done with c
```

If you do the same, but just change that one line back to:

```
 my $fp = *STDIN;
```

And you get Dumper reporting (rest of output snipped for brevity):

```
Process before open a: $VAR1 = *::STDIN
Process  after open a: $VAR1 = *::STDIN;
```

However it clearly *is* opening, because it's printing the file content.

If you fire up `strace` and run through the two processes (cut down thus):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $fh;
open ( $fh, "<", "fishfile" ) or warn $!;
print <$fh>;
```

And run this `strace myscript`. (Note - `strace` is a linux specific tool - there are others for other platforms)

(note - I'm using a file called `fishfile` with a content of `fish` because that way I am pretty sure I can find the text :))

Doing it twice - once with the assigning `STDIN` you'll see a couple of differences around the `open` operation.  Run them both through `diff` and you'll see there's lot of it but the interesting part is:

Without the `STDIN` assignment:

```
open ( "fishfile", O_RDONLY) = 3
read (3, "fish\n", 8192 )    = 5
write ( 1, "fish\n", 5 )     = 5
```

With the `STDIN` assignment:

```
open ( "fishfile", O_RDONLY) = 3
dup2 ( 3, 0 )                = 0 
close ( 3 )                  = 0
read (0, "fish\n", 8192 )    = 5
write ( 1, "fish\n", 5 )     = 5
```

(Note - return code for `open` is the file descriptor number - e.g. 3)

So what is it *actually* doing is:

- opening your new file
- duplicating it over file descriptor zero (which is `STDIN`)
- reading the new `STDIN`.
- write it to file descriptor `1` or `STDOUT`. (`2` is `STDERR`).

So as a result - because you are - by doing this - clobbering `STDIN` with your own file descriptor, and because `STDIN` is globally scoped (rather than your `$fh` which is lexically scoped):

- You are masking `STDIN` in sub process `b` and then reading it until EOF, which means when `a` gets to start reading it, there's nothing there.

If however you move the `open` to *after* the call to `b`:

```
sub process {
    my $name = shift;
    print "Starting process with $name from ", scalar caller(), " \n";
    my $fp = *STDIN;

    process('b') if $name eq 'a';
    print "Process before open $name: ", Dumper($fp), "\n";
    open $fp, '<', $name if $name;
    print "Process  after open $name: ", Dumper($fp), "\n";

    print "Processing file '$name' (fp=$fp)\n";
    print "Contents of $name:\n";
    print while (<$fp>);
    print "Done with $name\n\n\n";
}
```

That works successfully. I'm assuming based on your previous questions this is related to processing a file, then opening sub processes based on the content.

The solution would therefore be test for the existence of `$name` before cloning `STDIN` and you won't have the the problem.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I would not have thought of using `strace` to see what's really happening. You just taught me a method that will be very useful for many cases. Thanks.

Comment: I would also like to offer - your question is well constructed - it's a simple, repeatable example that demonstrates the problem. That makes figuring out what's going in considerably easier.

Comment: Clarification: the OP's script does not "[close] STDIN in sub process `b`"; instead it leaves STDIN open but at EOF, which "means when `a` gets to start reading it, there's nothing there."

Comment: Good point.  I was thinking of how best to phrase what is happening to STDIN because it is replaced, twice, but in neither case is it really closed per se. But still, the second replacement makes the previous one disappear

Answer (score 3):

```
my $fp = *STDIN;            
open $fp, '<', $name if $name;
```

is the same as

```
my $fp = *STDIN;            
open STDIN, '<', $name if $name;
```

You are instructing `open` to change `STDIN`. If you want to create a new handle, you need to pass an undefined scalar to `open`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
qx{echo "a file" > a};
qx{echo "b file" > b};
qx{echo "c file" > c};

process('a');
process('c');
process('');

sub process {
    my $name = shift;
    my $fp;
    if( defined( $name ) and length( $name ) ) {
      open $fp, '<', $name
    }else{
      $fp = *STDIN;
    }
    process('b') if defined($name) and $name eq 'a';

    print "Processing file '$name' (fp=$fp)\n";
    print while(<$fp>);
}
```

Tested using `echo stdin | perl scriptname`.

**WARNING** Switch to `if length($name)` from `if $name` to avoid "misbehaving" with a file named `0`.

Comment: I suspect the question is rather "why is it doing this?" rather than "how can I avoid it?"

Comment: As I understand **global** "STDIN glob as filehandle" is **reassigned** in called sub-procedure before calling procedure uses it.  _IMHO_ To be safe you should use in $fp assignemts IO::File constructor for named files and IO::Handle constructor for STDIN.

Comment: I would suggest testing `defined` rather than `length`.